# Function f(x) is continuous on the interval [0,2c]. If f(c) > f(0) and f(c) > f(2c), show that there is a ∈ [0,c] such that f(c+a) = f(a).

Tags: real-analysis

I need help with this question. Is there something to do with Intermediate Value Theorem? Not sure how to approach this. Appreciate any help, thanks!

Assume $c>0$ is a constant and the function $f(x)$ is continuous on the interval $[0,2c]$. If $f(c) > f(0)$ and $f(c) > f(2c)$, show that there is $a ∈ [0,c]$ such that $$f(c+a) = f(a)$$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the function $g(x):=f(x+c)-f(x)$ for $x \in [0,c]$

Show that $g(0)>0$ and $g(c)<0.$ Can you proceed ?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there something to do with Intermediate Value Theorem?

Yes, very much.

Take a look at

$$f(c+a) = f(a)\\f(c+a) - f(a) = 0$$
Can you make something intermediate-theoremy out of that?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Could I have more hints please? Do I have to add g(x)?

Comment: I gave you an equation where the right-hand side is $0$ and the left-hand side is some function. And I've told you that this is about the intermediate value theorem. What do you think?